# Excel 2013 conditional formatting using a formula

Tags: formatting, excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet in Excel 2013 with Location in Column A, Material Number in Column B and types or groups of materials sorted by material number in Column I J & K. Other columns contain data that is irrelevant here.

Column B can contain the same material number in multiple cells.

I'm trying to find a simpler way to format font and color of the items in Column B by comparing if the item is located in Column I J or K, or not at all (no formatting in that case).

I was entering an individual conditional rule to compare Column B with the value in cell I3, another rule for I4, another rule for I5 and so on.

This is getting unwieldy due to the number of items now in I J & K.

There has to be a simpler, more elegant way to do this. Conditional formatting using exact match is not letting me select a range of cells for the match value.

I just need to format the text in Column B to Bold and Blue if the number exists in Column I also, or Bold and Red if it exists in Column J or Bold and Green if it exists in Column K.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a conditional formatting rule that uses a formula. The formula can contain a Countif function that counts how many times the value in cell B in the current row is counted in column I. For example, starting in row 2, select B2 and add a formatting rule with the formula

```
=COUNTIF($I:$I,$B2)
```

Take care to use the current row number in the formula and don't use a dollar sign $ in front of the row number. Set three rules, one for column I, one for J and another one for K.

[image]

You don't need a new set of rules for each row. Just apply the three rules to all the rows required.

[image]